# Как анимировать движение одного ImageView к другому?

Tags: android

Скажем, есть img1, img2.
Я хочу, чтобы в анимации - первый двигался ко второму, где бы тот ни находился. При этом первый должен схлопываясь (scaleX), исчезать в конце (alpha).

```
      ObjectAnimator moveY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img1, "TranslationY", 0, img2.getTop());
      ObjectAnimator moveX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img1, "TranslationX", 0, (float)img2.getRight());
      ObjectAnimator hideAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img1, "alpha", 1, 0);
      ObjectAnimator smallAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img1, "scaleX", 1.0f, 0.0f);
      AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
      animatorSet.play(moveY).with(moveX).with(hideAnimator).with(smallAnimator);
      animatorSet.setDuration(DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION);
      animatorSet.start();
```

p.s. Получилось так: img1.animate().x(img2.getX()).y(img2.getY()).alpha(0.0f).scaleX(0.0f).setDuration(1000).start();

Comment: что не так с кодом, который в вопросе?

Comment: @pavlofff уезжает в другую сторону. Остальное работает. Я первый раз делаю анимацию с направлением и не уверен что правильные методы выбрал. Плюс есть некий ValueAnimator, но этот способ мне показался проще.

Comment: @pavlofff получилось так img1.animate().x(img2.getX()).y(img2.getY()).setDuration(1000).start(); Но пока не знаю как добавить остальные анимации.

Comment: Сделал. img1.animate().x(img2.getX()).y(img2.getY()).alpha(0.0f).scaleX(0.0f).setDuration(1000).start();

Comment: @pavlofff Вот только понять не могу, почему тот код не работал как надо... img2.getX(); я тоже там делал.

Comment: Плюс анимация не возвращается к началу, будто бесконечная.